# $\text{Hom}_{\Lambda}(\text{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(V,M_1), \text{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(V,M_2)) \cong \text{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(M_1,M_2)$?

Tags: category-theory, representation-theory, homological-algebra

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be an additive category, $M$ an object in $\mathcal{C}$, and $add(M)$ the full subcategory of $\mathcal{C}$ consisting of all direct summands of finite sums of copies of $M$. Suppose $X\rightarrow M_n \rightarrow \cdots \rightarrow M_2 \rightarrow M_1 \rightarrow Y$ is a (not necessarily exact) sequence of morphisms in $\mathcal{}$ with $M_i \in \textrm{add}(M)$.

Let $\Lambda$ be the endomorphism ring of $V$, where $V := X\oplus M$. And we have an exact sequence of $\Lambda$-modules: 
\begin{align*}
0 \rightarrow \textrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(V,X) \rightarrow \textrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(V,M_n) \rightarrow \cdots \rightarrow \textrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(V,M_2) \rightarrow \textrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(V,M_1 \oplus M) \rightarrow T \rightarrow 0. 
\end{align*}
In a paper, he says that "Applying
$\textrm{Hom}_{\Lambda}(-,\textrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(V ,M))$ to this sequence, we get a sequence which is isomorphic to the
following sequence
\begin{align*}
0 \rightarrow \textrm{Hom}_{\Lambda}(T,\textrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(V,M)) \rightarrow \textrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(M_1 \oplus M,M) \rightarrow \textrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(M_2,M) \rightarrow \cdots \rightarrow \textrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(M_n,M) \rightarrow \textrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(X,M) \rightarrow 0 
\end{align*}
So is there anyone tell me how to apply this functor $\textrm{Hom}_{\Lambda}(-,\textrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(V ,M))$ to get that sequence? Whether $\text{Hom}_{\Lambda}(\text{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(V,M_1), \text{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(V,M_2)) \cong \text{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(M_1,M_2)$?

Comment: No. You can find an example where, say, $\text{Hom}(V, M_1)$ is zero.

Comment: @ Qiaochu Yuan  If $\textrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(V,M_1)=0$, can we get $V=0$ or $M_1=0$?

Comment: I suggest to replace "addictive" by "additive". Counter example $\mathcal{C}$ is the category of abelian groups, $V=\mathbb{Z}_2$, $M_1=M_2=\mathbb{Z}_3$.

Comment: @Nex In your example, what is $M$? The title of the question may be somewhat misleading, because it leaves out the hypotheses that $M_1$ and $M_2$ are summands of multiples of $M$ and $V=X \oplus M$.

Comment: @Stephen My counter example was constructed before the OP changed the question (see the first version).

Comment: @Nex I see, thanks for clarifying!

Comment: $Hom_{\mathcal{C}}(V,M_i)$'s are projective $\Lambda$-modules.  The two sides of your question are both $e \Lambda f$ for some idempotent $e,f$ of $\Lambda$ (corresponding to the projection from $V$ to $M_1$ and $M_2$ repsectively).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can see lemma 3.1 in page 202 of "Elements of the Representation Theory of Associative Algebras 1". Note that $M_i\in\text{add}(M)\subset\text{add}(V).$

Comment: Only to proof when $M_1=V$. Repalce $M_1$ to $V$, you can get your answer.